# Configurate Protractor to ignore browser console errors

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, protractor

I try to write tests for web application, but there are some difficulties.
When i use the web application i got some angular errors in browser console. It is not fatal errors, and they do not interfere for aplication execution.

But when i run Protractor test, it fail on the first of this browsers console errors.

Is there a way to configure Protractor test to carried out test scenarie and checked the scenarie getting results, ignoring these browser console errors?

My test file:

```
var
    testingAdress = 'http://localhost:1340',

describe('admin avtorization test', function(){
    beforeEach(function(){
        // should be called before each it block
    });

    it('should avtorizate as admin', function(){

        browser.get(testingAdress);

        expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toEqual('localhost:1340'+'/#!/');

        //element(by.linkText('Sign Up')).click();

        //expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toEqual(testingAdress + '/#!/signup');

        //element(by.id('myLink').click());
        //expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toEqual("http://myUrl.com");
    });

});
```

My config file:

```
exports.config = {
    directConnect: true,

    // Capabilities to be passed to the webdriver instance.
    capabilities: {
        //'browserName': 'firefox'
        'browserName': 'chrome'

    },

    // Framework to use. Jasmine is recommended.
    framework: 'jasmine',

    // Spec patterns are relative to the current working directory when
    // protractor is called.
    specs: ['spec/avtorization_test.js'],

    // Options to be passed to Jasmine.
    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000
    },

    plugins: [{
        package: 'protractor-console-plugin',
        failOnWarning: false,
        failOnError: false,
        logWarnings: false
    }]
};
```

Here is my errors from browser console

```
unreachable code after return statement application.js:27995:8
Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: []
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.2/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5D
 application.js:71011:12
"Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: []
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.2/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5D
minErr/<@http://localhost:1340/js/application.js:71011:12
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$digest@http://localhost:1340/js/application.js:87720:1
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$apply@http://localhost:1340/js/application.js:87946:13
bootstrapApply@http://localhost:1340/js/application.js:72656:9
invoke@http://localhost:1340/js/application.js:75568:16
bootstrap/doBootstrap@http://localhost:1340/js/application.js:72654:1
bootstrap@http://localhost:1340/js/application.js:72674:1
[29]</</<@http://localhost:1340/js/application.js:120390:3
trigger@http://localhost:1340/js/application.js:74070:7
defaultHandlerWrapper@http://localhost:1340/js/application.js:74360:3
createEventHandler/eventHandler@http://localhost:1340/js/application.js:74348:9
" application.js:84237:18

Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: []
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.2/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5D
 application.js:71011:12
"Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: []
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.2/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5D
minErr/<@http://localhost:1340/js/application.js:71011:12
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$digest@http://localhost:1340/js/application.js:87720:1
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$apply@http://localhost:1340/js/application.js:87946:13
done@http://localhost:1340/js/application.js:82267:36
completeRequest@http://localhost:1340/js/application.js:82465:7
requestLoaded@http://localhost:1340/js/application.js:82406:1
"
```

Protractor test result   console text:

```
roman@rmk-pc:~/agroapp/test$ protractor config.js
Using ChromeDriver directly...
[launcher] Running 1 instances of WebDriver
Started
F

Failures:
1) admin avtorization test should avtorizate as admin
  Message:
    Failed: unknown error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
    Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: []
    http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.2/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5D
      (Session info: chrome=49.0.2623.87)
      (Driver info: chromedriver=2.21.371461 (633e689b520b25f3e264a2ede6b74ccc23cb636a),platform=Linux 4.2.0-34-generic x86_64)
  Stack:
    WebDriverError: unknown error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
    Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: []
    http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.2/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5D
      (Session info: chrome=49.0.2623.87)
      (Driver info: chromedriver=2.21.371461 (633e689b520b25f3e264a2ede6b74ccc23cb636a),platform=Linux 4.2.0-34-generic x86_64)
        at WebDriverError (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/error.js:27:10)
        at Object.checkLegacyResponse (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/error.js:580:13)
        at /usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:360:15
        at Promise.invokeCallback_ (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:1329:14)
        at TaskQueue.execute_ (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2790:14)
        at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2773:21)
        at /usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2652:27
        at /usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:639:7
        at process._tickCallback (node.js:369:9)
    From: Task: Run it("should avtorizate as admin") in control flow
        at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/jasminewd2/index.js:81:14)
        at /usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/jasminewd2/index.js:18:5
        at Promise.invokeCallback_ (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:1329:14)
        at TaskQueue.execute_ (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2790:14)
        at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2773:21)
        at /usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2652:27
    From asynchronous test: 
    Error
        at Suite.<anonymous> (/home/roman/agroapp/test/spec/avtorization_test.js:16:5)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/home/roman/agroapp/test/spec/avtorization_test.js:11:1)
        at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)

1 spec, 1 failure
Finished in 4.334 seconds
Warning from "protractor-console-plugin" plugin: SEVERE: http://localhost:1340/js/application.js 84237:24 Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: []
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.2/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5D
    at http://localhost:1340/js/application.js:71011:12
    at Scope.$digest (http://localhost:1340/js/application.js:87720:19)
    at Scope.$apply (http://localhost:1340/js/application.js:87946:24)
    at bootstrapApply (http://localhost:1340/js/application.js:72656:15)
    at Object.invoke (http://localhost:1340/js/application.js:75568:19)
    at doBootstrap (http://localhost:1340/js/application.js:72654:14)
    at Object.angular.resumeBootstrap (http://localhost:1340/js/application.js:72682:12)
    at <anonymous>:248:41
    at callFunction (<anonymous>:237:33)
    at <anonymous>:247:23
Warning from "protractor-console-plugin" plugin: SEVERE: http://localhost:1340/js/application.js 84237:24 Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: []
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.2/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5D
    at http://localhost:1340/js/application.js:71011:12
    at Scope.$digest (http://localhost:1340/js/application.js:87720:19)
    at Scope.$apply (http://localhost:1340/js/application.js:87946:24)
    at done (http://localhost:1340/js/application.js:82267:47)
    at completeRequest (http://localhost:1340/js/application.js:82465:7)
    at XMLHttpRequest.requestLoaded (http://localhost:1340/js/application.js:82406:9)
Warning from "protractor-console-plugin" plugin: SEVERE: http://localhost:1340/js/application.js 71011:12 Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: []
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.2/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5D
[launcher] 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[launcher] chrome #01 failed 1 test(s)
[launcher] overall: 1 failed spec(s)
[launcher] Process exited with error code 1
roman@rmk-pc:~/agroapp/test$
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not a default protractor behavior.

It sounds like you are using [`protractor-console-plugin`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor-console-plugin) with `failOnWarning` set to true, fix it:

```
plugins: [{
  package: 'protractor-console-plugin',
  failOnWarning: false,
  failOnError: true,
  logWarnings: true
}]
```

Comment: thanks for answer, but it is not a reason of test fail.
I has not installed that plugin before test. Now i try to install that plugin and configure it like this:                                                                       


   plugins: [{
          package: 'protractor-console-plugin',
          failOnWarning: false,
          failOnError: false,
          logWarnings: false
      }]
  


It does not help me. Protracktor test fails after console errors. There are some other mechanism, that fails test after console error. Do you know other configurations feature for this task.

Comment: @pj-infest interesting! Could you please provide more details: your protractor config and the test you are executing? Thank you.

Comment: @pj-infest could you please try upgrading protractor to the latest version and use `jasmine2` instead of jasmine - does it help? Thanks.

Comment: what is a name of jasmine2 npm pakage?

Comment: @pj-infest my bad, just leave it `jasmine` - latest protractor would use the latest jasmine - jasmine2 automatically.

Comment: when i ask this question i has instaled 3.2.1 version of protrctor.
Now i have update this module to the last npm version - 3.2.2.
But it does not help me. I have the same errors when i run 
protractor config.js command